# When do we have rigid body rotation in fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm studying articles about spinning drop method. In most of approaches, the fluid movements are taken as rigid body rotation.

My question is not about only spinning drop device, I want to know, when in nature do we have rigid body rotations for fluids. Should our fluids have large viscosity to considered rigid body rotation for them? If yes, why? or if no, so what features should they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigid body motion is something you can assume for the spinning drop method in part because, almost certainly, the actual instruments you use for it have small-diameter capillaries, the speed of rotation isn't insanely fast, and the instrument lets the drop settle down a bit before the measurement is actually taken. Correct me if I'm wrong.

For most fluids at most familiar physical scales, rigid-body rotation is something you have to work at. If you take a pail of water and put it on a record turntable at 33 1/3 rpm, you'd have to wait a fairly long time for rigid-body motion to set in (depending on how close to "rigid" you want). Even then, when it does settle down, it's not primarily from viscous forces, but from Ekman pumping (large-scale circulations caused by differential rotation); if you could somehow turn that off, it would take an even longer time.... you could calculate it given the equation I give below if you want.

But if you crank up the viscosity, or reduce the size, then rigid-body rotation can set in much faster.

If you put the fluid in a nice rotationally-symmetric container and rotate the container around its axis of symmetry, the e-folding time-scale for rigid body rotation to set in due purely to viscous forces is of order
$$
\tau \simeq \frac{D^2\rho}{\mu}
$$ 
where $D$ is the diameter of the container, $\mu$ is the dynamic viscosity, and $\rho$ is the density of the fluid. So, decreasing the diameter of the container (capillary) makes a *huge* difference. This relation by the way just comes from the Stokes term in the Navier-Stokes equations.

In the case of the spinning-drop method it's a bit more complex b/c you have two fluids, but that's the general idea.

It's also worth noting that certain vortices in fluids, esp 2D fluids, will have vortex cores that nearly rotate like rigid bodies, but that's a whole 'nuther topic.

(I had to look up "spinning drop method", which is something I had never heard of. Interesting! I had never heard of it, and I've been studying fluid dynamics for years. Nice question.)

Edit: to answer the question more precisely,

a) the answer depends on how close to "rigid" suffices,

b) higher viscosity helps - a 2x viscous fluid reaches rigid-body rotation 2x as fast,

c) smaller in diameter helps *tremendously* - a 2x smaller diameter reaches rigid-body rotation 4x as fast,

d) at fixed dynamic viscosity, reducing the density helps (not that you have much choice typically)

e) having corrugations or other surface roughness probably helps, but this gets a bit more complex b/c it probably won't make much difference for very viscous fluids, where the Reynolds number for the initial rotation speed is already small to begin with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sir, would you please give me more help about the equation you wrote for the time needed to reach rigid-body rotation? I mean where does this equation comes from?
and Please vote my question if you liked it!

Comment: And correct me if I'm wrong "We don't have actual perfect rigid-body rotation for fluids in nature, but we can have some fluids act really near to it"

Comment: @M.H.Muhamadi: I didn't get that equation from a book; the equation comes from dimensional analysis of the underlying diffusion equation for viscous forces, which is the Stokes equation. If you are more familiar with the Navier-Stokes equation, just eliminate the nonlinear (advective) term; also, ignore the pressure term since that's also irrelevant here.